# Discord ChatBot in python: How can I print something from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a ChatBot for Discord in python. I am creating a dictionary with questions and responses called responses. Whenever the user types in the question, it should give the appropriate response. But I got stuck and don't know how to print the response. The solution is probably pretty simple, but I feel like I'm missing something. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ":")

responses = {
    "WHAT'S YOUR NAME?": "My name is ChatBot!"
}

@client.event
async def on_ready() :
    print("I'm pretty much ready to talk...")

@client.event
async def on_message(message) :
    # When you say cookie, the bot responds with a cookie emoji
    if message.content.upper() == "COOKIE" :
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ":cookie:")

    # A simple question answerer
    if message.content.upper() in responses:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[message])


client.("Don't worry about my token")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the message content, not the message object itself.

```
responses = {
    "WHAT'S YOUR NAME?": "My name is ChatBot!",
    "COOKIE": ":cookie:"
}

@client.event
async def on_message(message) :
    content = message.content.upper()
    if content in responses:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, responses[content])
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the value in the dictionary you would need to do this

```
print(responses["WHAT'S YOUR NAME?"])
```

which would return the value assigned to that, in your case `My name is ChatBot!` would be the reply. You could replace the query any way you see fit, for example if your responses dictionary was this

```
responses = {
    "WHAT'S YOUR NAME?":"My name is ChatBot!,
    "COOKIE":":cookie:"
}
```

You could access cookie by just doing `reponses["COOKIE"]`

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I would have to keep writing that for every single question/answer?

Comment: @SKIENCE No, replace the part in the square brackets with what you want to search. For example you would just need to put message in there.

`responses[message]` and then send that to discord. No need for if statements for every output you need.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('message-here'):
        await message.channel.send('response-here')
```